# How to cite multiple references, which includes only the beginning and the last one?

Tags: bibtex, citing

Maybe it is a simple question, but I could not find the answer in internet yet.

I already get the following result:

Lorem ipsum [1,2,3,4,5]

What I want is:

Lorem ipsum [1-5]

thank you very much

Comment: `sort&compress` for natbib.

Comment: Depends on how you make your bibliography (so an example would be useful), but if you're using `natbib`, then see Johannes' comment.